# unable to connect to the docker daemon from a jenkins docker agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to build a docker image in a jenkins agent, so first of all i spun up the jenkins master container without mounting the docker socket volume as you can see bellow, i'm able to connect to the docker daemon from master agent using tls, but when running the pipeline the docker cli cannot reach out to the api, even though i supplied the docker certificate credentials,  now how can i connect to the docker daemon in a jenkins agent using tls , do you have any suggestions ?
Thank you

jenkisfile :

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    node {
      label 'jenkins-agent'
    }

  }
  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
      steps {
        cleanWs()
        checkout scm
      }
    }

    stage('Docker Build') {
      steps {
        script {
          withCredentials([dockerCert(credentialsId: 'ec19d1e1-bea2-4e75-9dac-49c49fbfa303', variable: 'DOCKER_CERT_PATH')]) {
            configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: '54e67686-6227-4d56-9606-cc23bdbad5d4', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')])
            { sh 'echo $DOCKER_HOST'
            sh ' mvn clean install -B -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS -DskipTests=True'
          }
        }
      }

    }
  }

}

}
options {
  skipDefaultCheckout()
  disableConcurrentBuilds()
}
}
```

docker compose file:

```
  - name: Spin up containers
    docker_compose:
        project_name: jenkins-nginx
        definition:
          version: '2'
          services:
            nginx:
              image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
              restart: unless-stopped
              privileged: true
              ports:
                - "80:80"
                - "443:443"
              volumes:
                - /home/ubuntu/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
                - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
              depends_on:
                   - jenkins
              networks:
                 - jenkins        
            jenkins:
              restart: unless-stopped
              image: jenkinsci/blueocean
              volumes:
                - jenkins-home:/var/jenkins_home
                - jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client
              networks:
                 - jenkins
              depends_on:
                   - jenkins-docker    
              environment:
                  VIRTUAL_HOST: jenkins-server.ga
                  VIRTUAL_PORT: 8080
                  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2376"
                  DOCKER_CERT_PATH: "/certs/client"
                  DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: "1"
            jenkins-docker:
              restart: unless-stopped
              privileged: true
              image: docker:dind
              volumes: 
                - /home/ubuntu/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home   
                - jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client
              networks:
                  "jenkins":
                    "aliases":
                       - docker
              environment:
                  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: /certs  
              ports:
                - "2376:2376"
          volumes:
             jenkins-docker-certs:
             jenkins-home:
          networks:
             jenkins:
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn when launching the  jenkins agent to perform a job and do the build, i get the error message : no docker host